# asp.net mvc share content directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

At this moment I have 2 project that use the same content directory (scripts, static html, images etc etc). Is there a way to share this directory between the two projects instead of maintaining both duplicate directories?

When I publish one of the projects it needs to include that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two options that come to mind are mapping a static asset folder as an application within the website in IIS, or creating a virtual path provider.

Some VPP related links:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/27/431650.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Virtual_Path_Provider.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx